# what is the best

Tags: power, battery-charging

1. `9v 1.67a`
2. `5v 3a`
3. `9v 2.2a`
   This is about chargers. what is the best option. can you help me?

Comment: Well, since I always prefer more power when everything else is equal, I'd pick (3). ;)

Comment: Best is in the eye of the beholder.  Best relative to what criteria?

Comment: worst to best, fairly objectively is: 2,1,3

Comment: The best one is the one which best meets the requirements of whatever you are charging.

Comment: It depends on what the device and power supply support. They are all useless power supplies if device does not work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Option three will deliver the most power ie:9x2.2 = 19.8W so if your goal is max power delivery then 3rd option .
If your goal is easy to manufacture then option 2 as producing 5V 3A is not much difficult these days.
If your goal is what is best for your battery's health then option 1 as it supplying sufficient power with less current.